# polynomials and electrostatics

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

In two dimensions, the [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) of the Laplacian is the natural logarithm, $\nabla^2 \ln|z| = \delta(z)$, so we can take log of a polynomial the sum of [delta-functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
\[ \nabla^2 \ln p(z) = \sum \delta(z - z_i) \]
where $z_i$ runs over the roots of $p(z)=0$.

The equation $\nabla^2 \phi = \rho$ is [Poisson's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%2527s_equation). In our case, the charge distribution is the sum of point charges.  I wonder if anyone has studied roots of polynomial equations by analogy to Electrostatics.

Answer (score 3):

For certain orthogonal polynomials, there is an electrostatic interpretation that goes back to Stieltjes.  For example, suppose we put charges of $(1+\alpha)/2$ and $(1+\beta)/2$ at $1$ and $-1$, respectively, and put $n$ particles with charge $1$ in between them.  Then the minimal energy configuration of the $n$ particles is at the roots of the $n$-th degree Jacobi polynomial with parameters $(\alpha,\beta)$.  See http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512293 for a survey of related results.